# Load or write settings on program start

Tags: ruby

Data is generated this way:

```ruby
def checkConfigurationsFile
    if File.exist?("./prefs/settings.conf") == true
      configFile = File.read("./prefs/settings.conf")
      options = JSON.parse(configFile)
      configData = {:multithreading => options['multithreading'],
                    :systemCores => options['systemCores']}
      mainmenu()

      elsif File.exist?("./prefs/settings.conf") == false
        configData = {:multithreading => false,
                      :systemCores => 1}

        configFile = File.open("./prefs/settings.conf","w")
        configFile.write(JSON.pretty_generate(configData))
        configFile.close
        checkConfigurationsFile()
      else
        puts "Something went terribly wrong!"
    end
end
```

This is a settings menu:

```ruby
    def openPreferences
    puts <<-PREFERENCES
        ####################################################
        #|                                                |#
        #|  Preferences                                   |#
        #|  ------------------                            |#
        #|   1. Using Multithreading? (Currently #{configData[multithreading]})                                             |#
        #|  2. Adjust Multithreading (Currently #{configData[systemCores]} are used)|#
        #|                                                |#
        ####################################################
    PREFERENCES
      print "Enter a number to change settings: "
      choice = gets.i 

      if blablabla
      ...
```

If the user decides to alter his configurations, he needs to be able to do. But it seems like I couldn't use the data generated in the `checkConfigurationsFile` method because they are private (and it makes no sense to pass them via arguments all around the program).

It produces this error message:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from dbaser.rb:214:in `<main>'
        2: from dbaser.rb:10:in `checkConfigurationsFile'
        1: from dbaser.rb:54:in `mainmenu'
dbaser.rb:205:in `openPreferences': undefined local variable or method `configData' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to pass configs everywhere, then you need to make it global. There's several ways of doing this.

For example, just replace all `configData` with `$configData`. Boom, it's done. But this may be frowned upon.

Or, a more "professional" approach is to use some kind of global singleton config object.

Something like this:

```
class ConfigData
  class << self
    attr_accessor :multi_threading, :system_cores
  end
end
```

Then

```
# write at startup
ConfigData.system_cores = options['systemCores']

# read in another place
ConfigData.system_cores
```

Comment: you made my day. Thanks for that!